# turn a column of values into specified intervals and output two columns in average value in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have three columns and would like to group first column into 0.5% -1%, 1%-5%, 5%-10%, 10%-15% intervals and output two columns with average values.

```
   loan_rate  wkly_rate   ret_fwd
0     0.0050   0.000096  0.003784
1     0.0075   0.000144  0.006989
2     0.0100   0.000192  0.007745
3     0.0125   0.000240  0.013878
4     0.0150   0.000288  0.002195
5     0.0175   0.000337 -0.007370
6     0.0200   0.000385 -0.019037
```

and I would like the output to be

```
loan_rate  wkly_rate  ret_fwd    
 0.5%-1%    0.000001    0.001                           
 1%-5%      0.000001    0.001                           
 5%-10%     0.000001    0.001                           
 10%-15%    0.000001    0.001
```

any efficient way without writing a loop?

Comment: Is this to be done with pandas?

Comment: yes using padans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using pandas' `pd.cut` + `groupby`-

```
df

   loan_rate  wkly_rate   ret_fwd
0     0.0050   0.000096  0.003784
1     0.0075   0.000144  0.006989
2     0.0100   0.000192  0.007745
3     0.0125   0.000240  0.013878
4     0.0150   0.000288  0.002195
5     0.0175   0.000337 -0.007370
6     0.0200   0.000385 -0.019037

bins=[0.5, 1, 5, 10, 15]
labels=['0.5%-1%', '1%-5%', '5%-10%', '10%-15%']
```

```
v = pd.cut(
    df.loan_rate * 100, bins=bins, right=False, labels=labels
)
df.drop('loan_rate', 1)\
  .groupby(v)\
  .mean()\
  .reset_index()

  loan_rate  wkly_rate   ret_fwd
0   0.5%-1%   0.000120  0.005387
1     1%-5%   0.000288 -0.000518
2    5%-10%        NaN       NaN
3   10%-15%        NaN       NaN
```